# using Substr and instr in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract the middle of the string from record. I want to get the only middle of the string.

```
select instr('WUK00000105376:WUKE03960761:WUKR0093868603',':') 
from dual;
```

I want to get only `WUKE03960761` from this string.

I have tried by using sustring and instring to get the output but i am not getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col,
              INSTR(col, ':') + 1,
              INSTR(col, ':', 1, 2) - INSTR(col, ':') - 1)
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `regexp_substring()` to get the string between the two colons:

```
select regexp_substr('WUK00000105376:WUKE03960761:WUKR0093868603',':[A-Z0-9]+:') 
from dual;
```

This however would also return the colons, but you can also tell `regexp_substr()` to return a specific group from the regex:

```
select regexp_substr('WUK00000105376:WUKE03960761:WUKR0093868603',':([A-Z0-9]+):',1,1,'i',1) 
from dual;
```

But Tim's solution using substr and instr is most likely going to be a lot faster.